# asp.net web form client with identity server 4

Tags: webforms, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver3, identityserver4

I have a asp.net solution which consists of

```
1). asp.net identity server rc 3
2). asp.net Core web api
3). asp.net webform ( not in asp.net core, client)
```

I don't see any sample with identity server 4 and web form client. Can you please suggest how to authenticate web form user using identity server with asp.net identity and then call api with the access token ?

I don't see identity server 4 sample with [web form client](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/dev/Clients/src) or [sample](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/dev/Quickstarts)

identity server 3 has a [sample](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/Clients/WebFormsClient)  but it is doing everything in [startup](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/blob/master/source/Clients/WebFormsClient/Startup.cs)

When i see [mvc client](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/dev/Quickstarts/6_AspNetIdentity/src/MvcClient/Startup.cs) for identity server 4, it has all settings in configure method and then calls it like [this](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/dev/Quickstarts/6_AspNetIdentity/src/MvcClient/Controllers/HomeController.cs)

How will i apply Authorize attribute in webform so that i am redirected to identity server 4 for login and then after login when i call api like this:

how to change client for webform ?

```
 new Client()
                  {
                    ClientId = "mvcClient",
                    ClientName = "MVC Client",                    
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,

                    ClientSecrets = new List<Secret>()
                    {
                        new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                    },

                    RequireConsent = false;

                    // where to redirect to after login
                    RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5002/signin-oidc" },
                    // where to redirect to after logout
                    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5002" },

                    AllowedScopes =
                    {
                        StandardScopes.OpenId.Name,
                        StandardScopes.Profile.Name,
                        StandardScopes.OfflineAccess.Name,
                        StandardScopes.Roles.Name,
                        "API"
                    }
                }

new InMemoryUser()
            {
                Subject = "1",
                Username = "testuser",
                Password = "password",
                Claims = new List<Claim>()
                {
                    new Claim("name", "Alice"),
                    new Claim("Website", "http://alice.com"),
                     new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, "admin")

                }
            }


 return new List<Scope>()
                {
                    StandardScopes.OpenId, // subject id
                    StandardScopes.Profile, // first name, last name
                    StandardScopes.OfflineAccess, 
                   StandardScopes.Roles,
                    new Scope()
                    {
                        Name = "API",
                        Description = "API desc",
                         Type = ScopeType.Resource,
                        Emphasize = true,
                        IncludeAllClaimsForUser = true,
                        Claims = new List<ScopeClaim>
                        {
                            new ScopeClaim(ClaimTypes.Name),      
                            new ScopeClaim(ClaimTypes.Role)
                        }
                    }
                };


 public void CallApiUsingClientCredentials()
                {
                    var tokenClient = new TokenClient("http://localhost:5000/connect/token", "mvc", "secret");
                    var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestClientCredentialsAsync("api1");

                    var client = new HttpClient();
                    client.SetBearerToken(tokenResponse.AccessToken);
                    var content = await client.GetStringAsync("http://localhost:5001/identity");

                    var result = JArray.Parse(content).ToString();

                }

 [Authorize(Roles="admin)]
          [HttpGet]
           public IActionResult Get()
                    {
                        return new JsonResult(from c in User.Claims select new { c.Type, c.Value });
                }
```

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 3):

Late answer, but hopefully it helps someone, still supporting web forms.
There is no problem to use startup together with web forms. The only limitation is no place for `AuthorizeAttribute` there, but it's still not a problem, just put:

```
app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate);
```

at the bottom of your

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
```

method within OWIN Startup.
An example Startup implementation [could be fetched from my github](https://github.com/dfrunet/SampleClients/tree/master/OidcClientHelper). It works with MVC, Web Forms and additionally brings JWT validation from IdentityServer v.3' codebase, upgraded to compile with the latest OWIN libraries.

If I still left anything unclear, don't hesitate to ask in the comments.

Comment: Perfect! Wish I would have came across this a few days ago.