# Right place of role based authorization

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, authorization

I want to granting access to the system in SPA that will be written in asp.net core and reactjs, for example limited users can't access to some page or can't see some menus...

I want to know how should i implement authorization? **in server side or client side** with react?

I think if it's in server side that is safe. **If i implement role base authorization with asp.net core(identity) can i use it in react side or not?**

Can anybody show me the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a look at the [React project template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization), to see how this can be done using [IdentityServer4](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4). See e.g. this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40844310/role-based-authorization-with-identityserver4) for information about how to use roles in such an approach.