# How to send access token from MVc client to api

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have mvc client application  which uses identity server 4 using cookie authentication.

Below is my Config:

```
 services.AddAuthentication(options =>
      {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
```

Http Client Method:

```
public async Task<IList<MenuModel>> GetMenusNavAsync()
                    {
                        var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync("api/Menu/GetMenusNavBar");
                         response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                        using var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                       return await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<List<MenuModel>>(responseContent);
                   }
```

Now i need to send access token to api controller inside http client. How to  get the access token from Identity server or Coockie. Pls suggest..Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you are logged-in, on MVC app, you can use `HttpContext.GetTokenAsync` extension to get the authentication tokens in the session. This is a standard ASP.NET Core extension method on `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication` namespace.

the code would look like:

```
public async Task<IList<MenuModel>> GetMenusNavAsync()
        {
            var accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");

            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

            var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync("api/Menu/GetMenusNavBar");
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            using var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            return await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<List<MenuModel>>(responseContent);
        }
```

Find a complete sample [here](https://github.com/nahidf-adventures/IdentityServer4-adventures/blob/master/src/MvcClient/Controllers/HomeController.cs#L46)

Comment: Thank you ..Actually i already gt the ansewer.. Pls let me know how to authorization works in mvc controller? if i put just  [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")] is enough?

Comment: For authorization you can just simply add [Authorize] attribute on the action. But if you are looking for role based authorization, need to add role claim to the access token first, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40844310/role-based-authorization-with-identityserver4) is a good post about it.

Comment: Is it possible to add this as part of a delegating handler?